# How to show elements of array with separate quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array shows like `["7,1"]` but I want to show it like ["7","1"]. I am actually getting ["7,1"] this from

```
this.user = [{id: 7, name: 'Jack'}, {id: 1, name: 'James'}]
this.user.map(function(item) { return item["id"]; })
```

Above code returns `["7,1"]` but I want it to return `["7","1"]`

Please help me find where I am going wrong.

Comment: This seems to work as expected mapping to `[7,1]`. There are no quotes.

Comment: No, the above code returns `[7, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use id.toString();

```js
const user = [
{ id: 7, name: "Jack" },
{ id: 1, name: "James" },
];
const array = user.map(({ id }) => id.toString());

console.log(array);
```